# Why does this simple annotation example is not rejected in Static Code Analysis?

Tags: sal

I'm using SAL to make sure that all code paths that create an object `X` should call `X::work()` before destroying it.

```
#include <sal.h>

class X {
    bool worked = false;
public:
    _Post_satisfies_(!worked)
    X() : worked(false) {}

    _Post_satisfies_(worked)
    void work() {
        worked = true;
    }

    _Pre_satisfies_(worked)
    ~X() {
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    X y; // Does not call work() but still passes the test anyway
    x.work();
}
```

When I remove `x.work()`, then there goes an error as intended:

`warning C28020: The expression 'this->worked' is not true at this call.`

But soon as I add `work()` for one object `x`, the other one `y` also seems to pass the test. Is there some problem in my annotation?

Comment: What optimization level are you using? Is the compiler optimizing-away `y` entirely?

Comment: I'm using default Debug configuration for VS2015 (except "Analysis on Build" turned on) on empty Win32 Console Application template, so I doubt that it was optimized out.